# Show accessory view in UITableView that is an inputView in an Xcode playground?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, swift-playground

The UITableView accessory view is not being displayed in a table view that is set to another view's input view and presented as such when that view becomes first responder.

For example, this code displays a table view controller with a single table view cell that has a checkmark for its accessory.

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
  }
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    1
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello world"
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    return cell
  }
}

let tableViewController = TableViewController()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = tableViewController
```

[image: Check]

When I set this same table view controller as the input view to a text field, it comes up when the user taps on the text field in gray.

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
  }
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    1
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello world"
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    return cell
  }
}

let tableViewController = TableViewController()

let textField = UITextField()
textField.backgroundColor = .gray
textField.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 20))

let frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 360, height: 780))
let view = UIView(frame: frame)

view.addSubview(textField)

textField.inputView = tableViewController.view
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

However, it is missing the checkmark accessory now.

[image: No check]

How can you show the accessory view on the UITableViewCell when the UITableView is used as an input view?

Answer (score 1):

Tried as Xcode project (works well as expected), and hold a reference to the table view controller, otherwise, it goes out of scope and deallocated (Not sure this is the root cause of the issue here).

[image: in simulator]

Source code, your table view controller and adding text field in storyboard and having a reference of table view controller in view controller.

```
  class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
  }
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    1
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello world"
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    return cell
  }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tx: UITextField!
    var tableViewController : TableViewController!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableViewController = TableViewController()
        self.tx.inputView = self.tableViewController.view
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a retain issue. It works in a project and not in a playground.